# Apache proxypass mangles url

Tags: apache-http-server, proxy

I'm trying to use my apache server to proxy another site, and it's *mostly* working. I can get the root page to proxy correctly, but any subdirectories or subpages are failing:

```
prxy.james.net -> target.net
prxy.james.net/css/main.css -> target.netcss
("dns lookup for target.netcss failed")
```

It looks like a trailing slash error, but I have trailing slashes *everywhere*.
Below are the entries for this subdomain as found in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName prxy.james.net
    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyPass               /       "http://target.net/"
    ProxyPassReverse        /       "http://target.net/"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName prxy.james.net
    ProxyPass               /       "https://target.net/"
    ProxyPassReverse        /       "https://target.net/"
</VirtualHost>
```

If you need any more information, let me know!
Cheers, James

Comment: How did you verify that the problem is with your proxy, and not with the target issuing a bad redirect?